# Illustrator CC, matching two layers (with Transform applied) that are from different files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

We have one Adobe Illustrator file layer and we want it to match up to a previous file layer.  Problem is the previous graphic artist did a rotate, which we know, but then some kind of transformation, so now we cannot match the two files at all.

We can get it close, but if we can't match it up perfectly, then we will have to digitize some lines again.  Is there a way to have an old layer match a new layer, their linework being very close.  It is a street layer and so must be precise as possible. Maybe Adobe CC has some tools to help?

Comment: can you provide some screenshot what are you trying

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no "automated" method to match one object to another short of alignment options.

The best you can often do is use Outline Mode and manually ensure paths overlap.

Not quite certain why you couldn't merely copy/paste from the original and use that, though (editing it as needed afterwards).